# What is the expected behavior when forming ZonedDateTime from Instant and ZoneId?

Tags: java, timezone, java-time

Given an Instant formed from a TimeStamp (such as '2016-06-07 08-01-55'), and a specific ZoneId ('Europe/Berlin'), what would be the expected result of this code?

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp.toInstant, zoneId)
```

Would it be

> '2016-06-07 08-01-55 +02:00'   (time doesn't change, but ZoneId is changed)

or

> '2016-06-07 10-01-55 +02:00' (time & ZoneId are changed)

I'm asking this question because I see both behaviors in different environments.

Comment: If you're seeing different behaviours, I strongly suspect that the instant you're using is different in the two cases. You haven't really given us enough information to reproduce this - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Or the zoneId is the system time-zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is deterministic, assuming you properly set each parameter. Using your data:

```
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 6, 7, 8, 1, 55);
ZonedDateTime zdt = datetime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();

Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(instant); //The timestamp you describe in your question

ZonedDateTime result = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));

System.out.println(result); //WILL ALWAYS PRINTS: 2016-06-07T08:01:55+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

Answer (score 2):

An instant is always counted from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Thus, creating a ZonedDateTime from an instant will convert the instant timestamp to the corresponding zone.

In your example it seems that the input timestamp does not contain zone information. Most probably, when this is parsed into an instant it will have a different result as most parsers will assume the timestamp is in the system default zone. That can result in different instants based on the system this is run on which in turn can result to the different behaviour that you observe.